# How to split string object and then concatenate and add to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, concatenation

This addtoTaskList function needs to split the received task into 2 arrays(?) or two tasks split by a comma, then concatenate them and add them to the tasks array. As the code is currently, it outputs the split values to the taskList, but also outputs a non-split duplicate and clears the task list after every entry as shown below:
 [image: Duplicate Output]

I mostly need help with the concatenation, I think-thanks!

```
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

var tasks = [];

var displayTaskList = function() {
    var list = "";
    // if there are no tasks in tasks array, check storage
    if (tasks.length === 0) {
        // get tasks from storage or empty string if nothing in storage
        var storage = localStorage.getItem("tasks") || "";

        // if not empty, convert to array and store in global tasks variable
        if (storage.length > 0) { tasks = storage.split("|"); }
    }

    // if there are tasks in array, sort and create tasks string
    if (tasks.length > 0) {
       // tasks.sort();
        list = tasks.join("\n");
    }
    // display tasks string and set focus on task text box
    $("task_list").value = list;
    $("task").focus();
};

var addToTaskList = function() {   
    var task = $("task");
    if (task.value === "") {
        alert("Please enter a task.");
    } else {  

        // add task to array and local storage
        var partsOfStr = task.value.split(',');
        tasks = partsOfStr.concat(task.value);

        localStorage.tasks = tasks.join("|");

        // clear task text box and re-display tasks
        task.value = "";
        displayTaskList();
    }
};

var clearTaskList = function() {
    tasks.length = 0;
    localStorage.tasks = "";
    $("task_list").value = "";
    $("task").focus();
};

window.onload = function() {
    $("add_task").onclick = addToTaskList;
    $("clear_tasks").onclick = clearTaskList;    
    displayTaskList();
};
```

Comment: Though not necessary, I recommend you use JSON.stringify(tasks) and JSON.parse(storage) instead of joining and splitting your array with "|" characters. That way if someone enters a "|" when adding a task, it doesn't add extra values to your tasks array.

Comment: Thank you!!! So sorry for wasting your time :( U are my hero man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to concatenate an array (`partsOfStr`) with a string (`task.value`). Perhaps you meant to use `tasks` instead of `task.value`?

```
tasks = partsOfStr.concat(task.value);
```

Should be:

```
tasks = tasks.concat(partsOfStr);
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, unfortunately I tried that previously, and it results in no output...

Comment: @JamesHolloway I can't seem to reproduce your issue. Are you making sure to assign the result of the `concat()` operation to tasks? `concat()` does not modify the original array, it simply returns a new concatenated array.

Comment: Oh my Lord Jason, I am so sorry man, your solution worked! I had a capitalization error-oof!! thank you so much